# check constraints not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
           ID   INT              NOT NULL,
           NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
           AGE  INT              NOT NULL CHECK (AGE >= 18),
           ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
           SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),       
           PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    );
```

I have created table. But it allowed me to add `age <18`. 
How to solve it . I need to check `age>=18`. how to  write query for that?

Comment: MySQL allows `CHECK` in DDL statements but unfortunately it serves as no purpose.

Comment: here's an alternative: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work

Comment: thank you @491243 I got an idea from that link

Answer (score 1):

The check command is parsed by all mysql storage engines. That's why it's not working. Either validate your data from PHP, or use a trigger, or use procedures to validate and insert data.